# Mysql view table with loop

Tags: mysql

Can anyone have idea regarding creating a view table to summarize the count of votes. e.g:
1. Select the distinct codes inside votes table
2. I want to create a view table to summarize the total votes from votes table according to distinct result of codes.

Currently i have this statement:

```
CREATE VIEW vote_summary AS
SELECT COUNT(*), code
FROM votes 
WHERE code = 292907005 //this should be get from the distinct result in vote table
AND chapter_id != 0
```

Basicaly i want to create procedural statement to collect the summary of the votes. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a best guess as to what you're looking for, instead of using `where` criteria, you actually want to use `group by`.

```
select count(*) cnt, code
from votes
where chapter_id != 0
group by code
```